# Javascript: cambio de tipo de valor de una variable

Tags: javascript

Leyendo sobre `JavaScript` encontré este ejemplo con dos notas:

```
var message = " hi ";
message = 100;
```

1) Declaramos `message` como `String` y luego la sobrescribimos como una variable de tipo *entero*, es válido pero NO recomendado.

2) Esto es admitido por `ECMAScript`.

> ¿Por qué no se recomienda cambiar el tipo de valor de la variable de esta manera?
>   ¿De qué manera sería más conveniente?

Comment: `javascript` **NO** es un lenguaje con tipado, a menos que uses `typescript`, un `string` puede pasar a un `number` y visceversa

Comment: Puedes usar tipado en JavaScript por medio de [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow). Es una librería para desarrollo, no funciona como "extensión" del lenguaje.

Comment: @Jorius: El formato de cita debería aplicarse al texto citado y no al revés.

Comment: @Rubén, lo que ocurre es que como me aplicaron ese formato en otras preguntas, decidi adoptarlo a esta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ver, vamos por partes:

En Javascript, al igual que en muchos otros lenguajes *interpretados*, las variables **no tienen tipo**; tienen tipo **los valores**, que es otra cosa.

Una variable es un *elemento* totalmente neutro: puedes asignarle el **valor** que quieras. El *tipo* de la variable lo determina, en todo momento, el tipo del **valor** que contiene: si la variable no existe o no tienen asignado ningún valor, estonces su tipo es `undefined`, y, a partir de ahí, va *adoptando* el tipo del valor que le asignamos nosotros: `number`, `string`, `object`, ...

En cualquier momento, podemos usar `typeof` para consultar **el tipo del valor** asignado a una variable.

El porqué no es conveniente asignar valores de distintos tipos a una misma variable es otro tema distinto: puede considerarse una *adaptación* del principio de *responsabilidad única*: usar una variable para una, y solo una, función o responsabilidad.

Este principio disminuye en gran medida la cantidad de errores en el codigo: si llamamos a una variable, digamos, `HoraDeInicio`, y decidimos que su valor será un objeto `Date` con la hora de inicio de cierta operación, **no deberíamos** usarla para, por ejemplo, contener la `string` con la representación en texto de dicha fecha/hora.

Así, en cualquier punto de nuestro código en el que veamos `HoraDeInicio`, sabemos lo que es y lo que contiene; mientras que si vemos `StringHoraDeInicio`, *deducimos* rápidamente que contiene una `string` con la representación en texto de la hora de inicio de algo.

Si usaras la primera para ambas cosas, **no** puedes saber *de un vistazo* el valor que contiene en un punto cualquiera de tu código; tendrías que mirar *hacia atrás*, buscando la última asignación, para saber el valor que contiene y si puedes usarla o no para cierta operación.

Comment: Gracias, si se que js define es el tipo por el valor, se que no es tipado, pero pregunte porque el libro decia que todo lo escrito era fiel o verdadero, entonfes dije porque ese problema de cambiar el tipo de valor, y como mas adelante no explica el porque de esa recomendacion decidi publicar la pregunta

Answer (score 3):

En realidad solo es cuestión de conceptos:

> **Tipado dinámico:** una variable puede tomar distintos tipos de datos en cualquier punto. Puede iniciar con string y luego pasar a number, etc. Este tipo de tipado lo implementan lenguajes interpretados (y parcialmente) como Python, Ruby, JavaScript.
>
> **Tipado estático:** la verificación de tipos se hace **en compilación** y no en ejecución, como el dinámico, lo que asegura una variable tenga un solo tipo durante su ciclo de vida. Este tipo de tipado lo implementan lenguajes como Java, C#, Haskell, etc.

Existen muchas discuciones sobre *¿Qué es mejor, tipado dinámico o tipado estático?*, pero al final no llegan a ningún punto. Cada enfoque tiene sus propias ventajas y desventajas. Te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages) en SO en inglés.

En términos generales, un tipado dinámico te permite ser más flexible, ya que no te preocupas por tipos en primera instancia, confiando en la calidad del código y testing para asegurar que no habrá resultados inesperados. Por otro lado, con un tipado estático se tiende a creer que "aseguras" coherencia entre tipos, pero esto no es totalmente cierto, ya que, en runtime pueden ocurrir casos inesperados que no pueden ser cubiertos en timepo de compilación.

Yendo directamente al lenguaje en consulta, JavaScript, no puedes tener un tipado estático porque interviene el diseño del lenguaje; sn embargo, lo que sí puedes hacer es definir tipos en JavaScript y trackearlos mientras desarrollas, esto por medio de [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow), una genial herramienta de Facebook. Flow tiene soporte para la mayoría de editores e IDEs.

Ejemplo JavaScript usando Flow:

```
async function findTweetsOf(id: String): Promise<Tweet> {
  let tweets: Array<Tweet> = await TwitterClient.findByUser(id);
  return tweets;
}
```

Si llamas a esa función con un valor diferente a String, lo que obtendrás es un error y te marcará la línea en el editor. Flow funciona muy bien con [ESLint](http://eslint.org/).

Comment: Leyendo, supongo que se podria decir que es dependiendo de la necesidad.?

Comment: @Victor-Random Sí, son enfoques diferentes. Si bien ambos pueden solucionar problemas comunes, usar uno u otro implica resolver problemas que el otro no. El tipado estático en JavaScript es bastante útil por ejemplo, cuando se hace librerías o en proyectos medianos/grandes.